# Unable to stop tap propagation with stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a custom card which has clickable elements. The whole element is wrapped in `<a>` tags while the inner clickables have a tap handler which uses preventDefault() and stopPropagation(). But, the click still bubbles up into the DOM.

The demo is shown [here](http://52.74.151.136:8080/custom_components/folder-card/demo.html).  The first card is not wrapped in the `<a>` tags, so the console logs the event handler response. How to stop the bubbling up of the internal clickables to the DOM?

**Update:**
Handling the on-click event in addition to on-tap event seemed to have done the required job at present. However, using the same function for both implies that both the handler functions are called. I want to use the same function for both that will be called only once. How to achieve this?

In addition, when `<paper-ripple></paper-ripple>` is used inside the element, neither of the tap or click events are fired when the internal clickables are clicked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `<div>` tags should never be inside `<a>` tags.

Secondly, BECAUSE your `<a>` wraps the `<div>` (rather `<folder-card>`)element, if you stopPropagation, then all that should happen is the link to the recipe cards. are you saying that the network event is firing too. or are you trying yo click the dots and only getting the link to the recipe page?

Place the `<a>` tag inside the `<folder-card>` and don't put other `<div>` inside it. Add CSS to make the `<a>` tag `display:block;` then use absolute positioning to to overlay the rest.

Comment: **Firstly:** A new update to you - HTML5 allows you to place block elements inside anchor tags. Welcome to the modern world!

**Secondly:** `<a>` is wrapping the `<folder-card>` element. Just inspect the element in chrome or view-source. When I click on the vertical dots, I dont want the recipe page to open, but a different action such as a drop-down menu to open. 
What you are talking about is old style HTML and CSS which is not needed anymore. Besides, if I want to do it that way, I would rather add a click listener to the div itself and route to the url.

Comment: HTML 5 states that the <a> element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".  

You are still doing it worng!

Comment: Hmm.. That makes sense. I will just switch to using a div and adding a tap listener then.

Comment: Well my answer basically identifies the issue you are having regardless of the HTML4/5 debate. it's because you wrapped the `<folder-card>` element that you aren't getting you menu click.  `stopPropagation()` is doing its job. And yes, I knew it was a `<folder-card>` element. I said as much. To me, for all basic intents, a custom element (unless prototyped) **is** a `<div>`.